# Analysis of survey data

Tags: repeated-measures, survey

This is the first time I am analyzing a survey. I have limited knowledge about stats and the best practices and would appreciate some pointers as to what kind of analysis I should perform on the data. The survey setup is:

- Testing two conditions: interface A vs interface B
- Each condition has 4 questions (same for both conditions)

  - 3 questions are 5-point likert scales (not sure, no difference, small difference, medium difference, high difference) and the last one is 5-point from (definitely no to definitely yes)
- There are 3 scenarios in which both conditions are tested

It is a within subjects design with the conditions across scenarios (6 possibilities) randomized. I have statistically calculated reference data which I will be using to compare the responses for each of the 4 questions, kinda like ground truth.

I know I am supposed to use non parametric tests. (Cochran Q test?)

Things I would like to do:

- I would like to make comparisons between responses for questions on the conditions (interface A vs interface B). : does this sound like a fredman test?
- Figure out if there is any way / any need to compare the results for questions against the reference values I have.
- Figure out what other analyses I should be doing

Comment: Likert-type questions usually assume at least an ordinal scale. If you assume this and you had paired-samples then a Wilcoxon signed-rank test is probably the way to go.

Comment: @ChrisNovak thanks, I'll look into it. I assume I can use the test to prove that the same person's responses to the two conditions are statistically different.

Comment: Yes, I would however advise first doing the omnibus test and then to use the appropriate correction for multiple testing when doing the post hoc tests (testing pairs for each condition). Btw, in the social sciences many people use parametric tests for likert-type scales, are you sure this is not an option for you?